# DynamoDB Query with key condition and filter expression by array contains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, dynamodb-queries, aws-sdk-nodejs

I want to query a DDB GSI with key condition, and apply filter on returned result using `contains` function.

Data I have in DDB table:

```
{
  "lookupType": "PRODUCT_GROUP",
  "name": "Spring framework study set",
  "structureJson": {
    "productIds": [
      "FBCUPOQsrp",
      "Y4LDaiViLY",
      "J6N3UWq9CK"
    ]
  },
  "ownerId": "mT9R9y6zGO"
}

{
  "lookupType": "PRODUCT_GROUP",
  "name": "Relational databases study set",
  "structureJson": {
    "productIds": [
      "QWQWQWQWQW",
      "XZXZXZXZXZ"
    ]
  },
  "ownerId": "mT9R9y6zGO"
}

...
```

I have a compound GSI (ownerId - HASH, lookupType - RANGE).

When I try to query the DDB (query structure is in "2" field) I get the result (the result is in "3"):

```
{
   "0":[

   ],
   "2":{
      "TableName":"Products",
      "IndexName":"ProductsOwnerIdLookupTypeIndex",
      "KeyConditionExpression":"#ownerId = :ownerId and #lookupType = :lookupType",
      "FilterExpression":"contains(#structureMember, :memberId)",
      "ExpressionAttributeNames":{
         "#ownerId":"ownerId",
         "#lookupType":"lookupType",
         "#structureMember":"structureJson.productIds"
      },
      "ExpressionAttributeValues":{
         ":ownerId":"mT9R9y6zGO",
         ":lookupType":"PRODUCT_GROUP",
         ":memberId":"FBCUPOQsrp"
      }
   },
   "3":{
      "Items":[

      ],
      "Count":0,
      "ScannedCount":2
   }
}
```

The returned result set is empty, despite I have data with given field values.

How I see the query (or what I want to achieve):

1. When I query the GSI with `ownerId = mT9R9y6zGO` and `lookupType = PRODUCT_GROUP` it will find 2 items - Spring and Relational DB sets
2. As the second step DDB will scan the returned query result with `contains (structureJson.productIds, FBCUPOQsrp)` filter expression and it should return one result to me, but I get empty set

Is something wrong with the query or do I miss some point in DDB query workflow?

Comment: Could you kindly add the whole structure of the query you're making? (per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)

Comment: Hi @RyanMarvin! The query structure is under the node "2". I use node sdk (documentClient.query(params) funnction)